# NTLM Basic authentication fails behind http apache only when load balancing

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, jboss, ntlm

I set up an apache `http` reverse proxy and load balance.

I already know that Reverse Proxying will break `NTLM` dialog, and leads to something like Basic Auth against Active Directory, which is sufficient for me.

`NTLM` is supported by jCIFS on my JBoss, and is working fine when:

- I use my JBoss address directly (`10.1.2.12:8080/myapp`)
- I use my apache RP address  (`myapp-homintranet.myorg.com/myapp`) **without a 2nd member**

But since adding second member to load balancing, it don't work at all !

```bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName myapp-homintranet.myorg.com
  ServerAlias myapp-homintranet

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass /myapp balancer://jbosscluster/myapp stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=On
  ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://server01.myorg.com:8080/myapp

  #Conf load-balancing Jboss
  <Proxy balancer://jbosscluster>
    BalancerMember http://server01.myorg.com:8080
    BalancerMember http://server02.myorg.com:8080
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
  </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

If I remove the second member (server 02), it works again.

I don't know how to solve this. Can someone help me ?

PS : If there is a way to highlight `apache/conf` syntax, tell me !

---

My workers `conf`, in case ...

```properties
# Define list of workers that will be used
# for mapping requests
worker.list=loadbalancer,status

# Define Node1 = server01
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=10.1.2.11
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.lbfactor=1
#worker.node1.cachesize=10

# Define Node2 = server02
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.node2.port=8009
worker.node2.host=10.1.2.12
worker.node2.type=ajp13
worker.node2.lbfactor=1
#worker.node1.cachesize=10


# Load-balancing behaviour
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=SERVER1_node1,SERVER2_node1
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1

# Status worker for managing load balancer
worker.status.type=status
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any real solution to this issue.
We just changed our auth method (using Kerberos and `mod_auth_kerb`, which were painful to configure).

I think there was an issue between the virtual `IP` and the Windows realm. We also encountered this problem with Kerberos. But we have not tested it again.

I hope this will help someone.